# Update MySQL table with smallest value from another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have been looking around quite a lot but I can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

I got two tables:

```
|---------------------|-------------------|
|         ID          |        Value      |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|          1          |        NULL       |
|          2          |        NULL       |
|          3          |        NULL       |
|          4          |        NULL       |
|---------------------|-------------------|
...
```

```
|---------------------|-------------------|
|         ID          |        Value      |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|          1          |          7        |
|          1          |         18        |
|          2          |         21        |
|          2          |          2        |
|          4          |        103        |
|---------------------|-------------------|
...
```

Basically what I wanna do is update the NULL-fields from the first table with the smallest value from the second table where there are matching IDs.
So that in the end it looks something like this:

```
|---------------------|-------------------|
|         ID          |        Value      |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|          1          |          7        |
|          2          |          2        |
|          3          |        NULL       |
|          4          |         103       |
|---------------------|-------------------|
...
```

I tired out a bunch of things but failed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Weird, I know, but I don't answer questions with 'wanna' in them, but for the benefit of others, it might be useful to share what you tried.

Comment: Even simply naming the two tables would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a sub query:

```sql
update t1
inner join (select ID, min(Value) as minimum from t2 group by ID) tempt2 on t1.ID=tempt2.ID 
set t1.value=tempt2.minimum;
```

Basically, you're looking up that minimum value in the second table for each ID, you call that table `tempt2`, and you join on that.